# What is host_build in qmake?

Tags: qt, qmake

I often see the condition host_build in .prf files, e.g.

```
host_build|staticlib: CONFIG += static
```

What is the meaning of host build? In what situation is host_build set to true?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, if `host_build` is true then target machine ("host") will have the same architecture as current machine ("build"), i.e. the project is **not** being cross-compiled.

Also note that so-called "Canadian Cross" is not supported by qmake.

UPD. By default `qmake` sets `host_build` to false and uses `QMAKE_XSPEC` as host specification. Usually it does not matter as `QMAKE_XSPEC` is the same as `QMAKE_SPEC` (see `qmake -query`). But if you need to make sure `host_build` is also set you have to do it manually by adding `option(host_build)`.

Comment: I am building Qt 5 binaries(in another directory rather than the source directory) from source code on Windows10 64 bit using mingw64 kit. I did not provide any option when running the configure.bat script. So the target machine has the same architecture as current machine? Unfortunately, the host_build is false, why?

Comment: do you mean I need to configure qt as "configure.bat -host_build"? What does this mean exactly? There are many codes based on the host_build condition. What is the difference between using and not using the host_build option as to the build result?

Comment: @William That must be added to .pro file.

Comment: but I seldom see the option(host_build) condition in .prf/.pro file, just a lot of bare host_build.

Comment: @William "Normal" projects do not use host_build at all.